# React testing userEvent element.animate is not a function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to test my login button (it has a ripple effect animation) and I want to see if it navigates to the login page. This is what I have but the console reports that element.animate is not a function, which I think is due to ripple effect animation?. How do I fix this code? Thanks!

Here's the Button

```
           <Button
            variant="gradient"
            size="sm"
            className="hidden lg:inline-block bg-tertiaryColor text-mainFontColor normal-case"
            onClick={navigateLoginpage}
            data-testid="navbarLogin"
          >
            <span className="text-sm">Login</span>
          </Button>
```

Test code

```
import React from "react";
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import App from "../App";

test("should render page and navigate to login page", async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  render(<App />);

  const mastheadText = screen.getByText(
    /lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua\. nunc sed blandit libero volutpat\./i
  );

  // rendered Homepage
  expect(mastheadText).toBeInTheDocument();

  user.click(screen.getByTestId("navbarLogin"));

  // navigated to login page 
  expect(screen.getByText(/don't have an account\?/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Test Console

```
Error
 FAIL  src/pages/Home.test.js
  × should render page and navigate to login page (409 ms)
                                                                                                             
  ● should render page and navigate to login page                                                            
                                                                                                             
    TypeError: element.animate is not a function                                                             
                                                                                                             
      16 |   expect(mastheadText).toBeInTheDocument();                                                       
      17 |                                                                                                   
    > 18 |   await user.click(screen.getByTestId("navbarLogin"));
         |   ^
      19 |
      20 |   expect(screen.getByText(/don't have an account\?/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
      21 | });

      at Ripple.applyAnimation (node_modules/material-ripple-effects/index.js:39:13)
      at Ripple.create (node_modules/material-ripple-effects/index.js:77:10)
      at onMouseDown (node_modules/@material-tailwind/react/components/Button/index.js:1:3889)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4164:14)       
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:338:25)   
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
```